# Is there an engine database that would include information on number of HPT blades per engine?

Tags: turbofan, turbine, datasets, blade

I am attempting to compile information on the number of high-pressure turbine blades across a wide range of turbine engines. Currently, I have only been able to find this information through brut force searching and I wanted to know if an engine database with this type of granular information exists?

Additionally, I have searched through Jane's but wasn't able to locate the appropriate information.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So... you're looking for a database of information to populate a database of information? Make sure you have the appropriate permission to appropriate their data into your database...

Comment: For the stages: It's not 100% complete but you may try http://www.jet-engine.net/civtfspec.html (military section also exists).